# QWebView: Get size of the content

Tags: qt, size, qwebview

does anybody know how to retrieve the Size of the content within a `QWebView`?

I've tried

```
QWebView v;
...
v.page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize();
```

but this always returns `640x480`, independend of the current `Content`.

Comment: The content size is usually corresponds to the frame's size, no?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be valid. Even a Text like "FooBar" renders to a Framesize of  800x600

Comment: If you want to test that idea just create an html file, load it into a browser and start to resize the browser window. The size of content will be visible when scroll bars will appear in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

There are two caveats with the mentioned `v.page().mainFrame().contentsSize()`.

#### wait until the page has finished loading

The mentioned method only works properly if the content has finished loading. You can not call it directly after a call to `v.load(QUrl("https://example.com"));`. Instead, connect to the [`loadFinished(bool)`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#loadFinished) signal and wait for it to be emitted. Even if you set some static HTML with no external references with [`v.setHtml(const QString&)`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml), you still have to wait for the `loadFinished(bool)` signal to be emitted.

#### set `preferredContentsSize` to a smaller value

If your page is smaller than 800x600, then you probably want to set the [`QWebPage::preferredContentsSize`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html#preferredContentsSize-prop) to something small before loading the new page. If you do not do that, the `v.page().mainFrame().contentsSize()` will always return 800x600. However, the page will not be rendered wider than the specified preferred width but it can be rendered higher/longer than the specified height.

You should decide on a `QWebPage::preferredContentsSize` **before** loading the first page. Prepare for heavy rendering bugs when passing a smaller size than the `QWebView` widget had before to `QWebPage::setPreferredContentSize` after a previous page has already been rendered. (I am using Qt 5.212.0)